# java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. (After editing my post)

Tags: android

building android,location based application. I have my class that initiate google maps api work (MygoogleMapsActivator). this is constractor of this class

```
public MyGoogleMapsActivator(Context mContext)
    {
          this.mContext = mContext;
    }
```

.
Context mContext is a activity where i need to display map and address,a pass it here for getting services that i need to activate.Activity displaying the results - my location and address(location and address i am getting from MyGoogleMapsActivator)

when i want to display it on my activity i get this exception in LogCat: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
i am getting ti from this function:

```
    public void SetUpTextViewWithAddress()
        {
             text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.address);          
             text.append(addressString);
             setContentView(text);
        }

How can i solved it,thanks.
This is full code of my activity:


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_new_place);

                mGoogleMapsActivator = new MyGoogleMapsActivator(this);

                Button buttonAddPlace = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddPlace);
                Button buttonAddByAddress = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddByAddress);

                fm = (SupportMapFragment ) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                buttonAddPlace.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(AddNewPlaceActivity.this, AddByAddress.class);

                        mMyPlace = new Places("", city, street, number, "", LoggedWithFacebookMainActivity.GetLoggedInUserName(), myPosition.latitude, myPosition.longitude);
                        intent.putExtra("Place", mMyPlace);
                        //intent.putExtra("TheStreet", street);
                        //intent.putExtra("TheNumber", number);
                        intent.putExtra("Clarification");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

                buttonAddByAddress.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent intent = new Intent(AddNewPlaceActivity.this, AddByAddress.class);

                        mMyPlace = new Places("", city, street, number, "", LoggedWithFacebookMainActivity.GetLoggedInUserName(), myPosition.latitude, myPosition.longitude);
                        intent.putExtra("Place", mMyPlace);
    //                  intent.putExtra("TheStreet", "Street");
    //                  intent.putExtra("TheNumber", "Number");
                        intent.putExtra("Clarification");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

                mGoogleMapsActivator.SetUpMapIfNeed(fm);
            mGoogleMapsActivator.SetMyGoggleActivatorLocationEnabled();
            mGoogleMapsActivator.SetUpService();
            mGoogleMapsActivator.setUpListener();
            mGoogleMapsActivator.SetUpAndGetProvider();
            mGoogleMapsActivator.SetMyLocationWithListener();
            mGoogleMapsActivator.SetMyPosition();
            mGoogleMapsActivator.SetUpMyMarker();   
            mGoogleMapsActivator.SetUpMapView();
            mGoogleMapsActivator.SetUpAddressFromGeocoder();
            city = mGoogleMapsActivator.getCity();
            street = mGoogleMapsActivator.getStreet();
            number = mGoogleMapsActivator.getNumber();
            addressString = mGoogleMapsActivator.getAddressString();
            SetUpTextViewWithAddress();
            mGoogleMapsActivator.AnimateCamera();

  public void SetUpTextViewWithAddress()
    {
         text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.address);          
         text.setText(addressString);
        // setContentView(text);
    }
```

}

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="end"
    tools:context=".AddNewPlaceActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="370dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/address"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonAddByAddress"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/map"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonAddPlace"
    android:text="@string/place_address_he" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonAddPlace"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonAddByAddress"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/address"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button_main"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:text="@string/add_place_he" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonAddByAddress"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button_main"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/add_place_manually_he" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the TextView is already attached to your view hierarchy. I'm guessing the view with address id is already inside the main layout file you are using for your activity, without the full activity code it's hard to tell. If this is true you should remove the setContentView call as it isn't needed. Make sure you want to append the text to what may already be in the TextView, if you want to replace the text you should use setText instead of append.

Comment: i removed it,but still same exception